# C - parameter in function can't handle int if declared as int*

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I want to use the C function called *is_subsetOf()* in two different ways:

Way 1: int* a and int* b are arrays with sizes >=2.
Way 2: int* a has size >=2, but int* b is only size 1, which means b is an int.

How can I force C to be okay with int* b being of size 1? Or is this not possible in C? An int IS an array of size 1??

```
int* is_in(int *left_hand, int n_l, int *right_hand, int n_r) {
  int *get_bool;
  get_bool = malloc(sizeof(int)*n_l);

  for (int i=0; i<n_l; i++) {
    if (is_subsetOf(right_hand, n_r, *(left_hand+i), 1)) {
      *(get_bool+i) = 1;
    }
  }
  return (get_bool);
}

int desc(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int is_subsetOf(int *a, int n_a, int *b, int n_b) {
  qsort(a, n_a, sizeof(int), desc);
  qsort(b, n_b, sizeof(int), desc);
  int v = includes(a, n_a, b, n_b);
  return(v);
}
```

Here are the messages I get from the compiler. It's just a warning, I know, but I'd like everything to be clean.

```
tmp.c: In function ‘is_in’:
tmp.c:73:47: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘is_subsetOf’ makes pointer 
from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     if (is_subsetOf(right_hand, n_r, *(left_hand+i), 1)) {
                                  ~~~~~~~~~^~~
tmp.c:37:39: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 int is_subsetOf(int *a, int n_a, int *b, int n_b) {
```

Comment: `*(left_hand+i)` should be `&left_hand[i]` or just `left_hand+i`

Comment: Your function doesn't take an array, it takes a pointer to an array. The array itself is a contiguous chunk of memory, and the pointer is the address of the first element of that memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int* a and int* b are arrays with sizes >=2.

No, they are pointers and they don't have any size. You probably meant that you pass arrays through them, but they **are not** arrays. Know that there is a difference.

> An int IS an array of size 1

No, `int a[1];` is an array of size 1; `int a;` is just `int`. But arrays can decay into pointers to their first element and variables have addresses, so this is correct:

```
int a[1];
int b;
int* ptr1 = a;//Points to the a[0]
int* ptr2 = &b;
```

Both are now same type and can be used in the same way. Of course you don't know if the `int` is followed by any more ints in memory, that kind of checking is up to the programmer (usually by passing the length param as you do). The following is the code you are actually looking for:

```
is_subsetOf(right_hand, n_r, left_hand+i, 1)
```

Pointers can be incremented, `left_hand+i` will point to the i-th `int` after the `int` to which `left_hand` currently points to. Again, validity of such pointer is up to programmer.

The compiler warning is quite important here, because `*(left_hand+i)` is of type `int` and the compiler warns that it will treat is as `int*`. Essentially looking that the value of `int` as an address to memory. That's not at all what you want and it **is** **an error**.

Comment: This was really helpful - thank you! I am more than a bit rusty with C!

Comment: @areyoujokingme No problem, it's not really a syntax-friendly language :)